# Intuition Behind Coefficient of Determination in Linear Regression

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(feature_train,target_train)
print(reg.coef_)
print(reg.intercept_,reg.score(feature_test,target_test))
```

P.S: Correct me If I am wrong in understanding `reg.score()`.

I have a doubt regarding `reg.score()` which is the last statement.  I know larger this score is better the model also that this is r squared value.

r squared value: As I know it indicates how much change in the value of Y is explained by a change in X.  so it's value must be in between 0 and 1.

But when I am running it I am getting value around -1.4 which is less than
0.  I am not getting why this is happening. Please explain me this and if it can take negative value what this negative value signifies.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183265/what-does-negative-r-squared-mean. This has what I need.

Comment: Arguably, the answer to your question lies in the linked SE post; plus that, according to the [scikit-learn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score), R^2 can indeed be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I am running it, I am getting value around -1.4 which is less
>   than 0.  I am not getting why this is happening.

This can happen with [*adjusted* R-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2).  The interpretation is this: your set of predicted values does a worse job of predicting the actual values, than does a straight line drawn horizontally at the mean value of your actual values.  This is what is referred to in the sklearn docs when they indicate that the fitted model "can be arbitrarily worse."

Answer (score 1):

The R-squared value (R2) can be calculated as:

R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_variable_variance)

If you use numpy arrays, you can find these values easily as:

absolute_error_array.var()

and

dependent_variable_array.var()

and manually calculate the R-squared value to find the problem.

Comment: Yes,you are right we can do that. But my concern is that in regression model r^2 value is between 0 and 1.But I am getting negative also I am not getting what this negative value signifies.

Comment: The manual calculation I described will verify the value is correct or not. If the manual calulation also gives a value of -1.4, this means that the R-squared value of 1 - (variance ratio) is giving 1 - 2.4, and that the error variance is *much* worse than the data variance itself, or in other words the model does an extremely poor job of describing the data.